# Why would I want to use unit scale? (Libgdx)

Tags: libgdx, bitmap-fonts

I have looked into the [SuperKaolio](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/superkoalio/SuperKoalio.java) example on Libgdx github repo. It is basically a test for integrating Tiled maps with Libgdx. They are using the unit scale 1/16 and if I have understood it correctly it means that the world no longer is based on a grid of pixels but on a grid of units (each 16 pixels wide). This is the code and comment in the example:

```
// load the map, set the unit scale to 1/16 (1 unit == 16 pixels)
map = new TmxMapLoader().load("data/maps/tiled/super-koalio/level1.tmx");
renderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(map, 1 / 16f);
```

I am basically wondering why you would want to do that. I only got problems doing it and can't see any obvious advantages.

For example, one problem I had was adding a BitMap font. It didn't scale at all with the background and one pixel in the font occupied an entire unit. [Image here.](http://imgbin.org/images/13434.jpg)

I'm using this code for drawing the font. It's a standard 14 points arial font included in libgdx

```
BitmapFont font = new BitmapFont();
font.setColor(Color.YELLOW);

public void draw(){
   spriteBatch.begin();
   font.draw(batch, "Score: " + thescore, camera.position.x, 10f);
   spriteBatch.end();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume there is a handy reason to have a 1/16th scale for tiled maps (perhaps for doing computations on which tile is being hit or changing tiles (they're at handy whole-number indices).

Anyway, regardless of what transformation (and thus what "camera" and thus what projection matrix) is used for rendering your tiles, you can *use a different camera for your UI*.

Look at the [Superjumper demo](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/demos/superjumper/superjumper/src/com/badlogicgames/superjumper/GameScreen.java), and see it uses a separate "guiCam" to render the "GUI" elements (pause button, game over text, etc).  The `WorldRenderer` has its own camera that uses world-space coordinates to update and display the world.

This way you can use the appropriate coordinates for each aspect of your display.

Comment: Didn't know you could use different cameras, but it makes plenty of sense and made everything a lot easier. Thanks for the answer!